# Converting unsigned char * to char *

Tags: c++, pointers, type-conversion

here is my code:

```
std::vector<unsigned char> data;
... // put some data to data vector
char* bytes= reinterpret_cast<char*>(imageData.data());
```

My problem is that in vector 'data' I have chars of value 255. After conversion in bytes pointer I have values of -1 instead of 255. How should I convert this data properly?

**EDIT**

Ok, its come up that I really dont need conversion but only a bits order. THX for trying help

Comment: -1 is the same bit pattern as 255 when viewing the char as signed. A signed byte can only represent the values -128..+127.

Comment: What are you really trying to do? 255 will be -1 so you won't get this to work.

Comment: if you are working with an image library that expects char * instead of unsigned char *, do not worry about the reinterpret_cast, it is doing the job perfectly. Signedness will be important when performing arithmetic operations on the data when used as integer values.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`char` can be either signed or unsigned depending on the platform. If it is signed, like on your platform, it has a guaranteed range from `-128` to `127` by the standard. For common platforms it is an 8bit type, so those are the only values that it can hold. This means that you can't represent `255` as a `char`.

Now to explain what you are seing: The typical representation of signed numbers in modern processors is two's-complement, for which `-1` has the maximum representable bitpattern (all ones), which is the same as `255` for `ùnsigned char`. So the cast does exactly what you ask it to: reinterpreting the `unsigned chars` as `(signed) chars`.

However I can't tell you how to convert the data properly, since that depends on what you want to do with it. The way you are doing it might be fine for your purposes, if it isn't your only choice is to change the datatype.

Answer (score 2):

This works as it should. Your `char` type has a size of 1 byte which equals to 8 bits. If it's unsigned, all of the bits are used to hold the value, which makes the maximum value that a `char` can hold 255 (2<sup>8</sup> = 256 different values, starting with 0).

In case of `signed char`, one bit is used to hold the sign instead of the value, which leaves you only 7 bts for the value, allowing to store numbers from -128 to 127.

So, when you hold 255 in a `unsigned char`, all the bits are interpreted as the value, thus you have 255. If you convert it to `signed char`, the first bit starts to be treated as the sign bit, and the data in the variable starts to be interpreted as -1.